# HTTP interface for VLC. Combining Loop & Repeat functions

Tags: http, vlc

I have a cd player I'm writing in Java, porting VLC with the http interface.  I'm trying to combine the loop and repeat functions in order to have a Repeat button with 3 states (Repeat none, Repeat One, and Repeat All).  For some odd reason, the "loop" boolean is switching back and forth every second, so there is no way to reliably "Repeat All".  I just have to hope the loop boolean is in the right state at the right time.  But as it is changing every second, this seems almost impossible to use.  Has anybody seen this?  Or know any solutions?

OK I FOUND IT.  Apparently you must explicitly put --loop or --no-loop in the parameters when you start up VLC via command line.  If you don't do that, it just keeps flip flopping back and forth, and you will really only have a 50% chance of getting what you want to happen.  If you choose one or the other at startup, you can at least change them whenever you want, without worrying about them reverting.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not as a part of your original question, just like that others can know that your question has an answer from the SO research tool.